# What is the difference between Label and Text in Qt5?

Tags: qml

I am new in using Qt creator and QML language. recently I have seen two classes named Label and Text. What is the difference between them?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Just looking at the documentation you can see that [Label](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html) derived from [Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) and adds 2 new properties - [background](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html#background-prop) and [palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html#palette-prop). Learn to use Qt documentation, that really helps you in development. Another different is that one set is Qt.Controls 2 and another one is Qt.Quick.

Answer (score 5):

First, there are two Quick Controls modules that you can use, 1 and 2. You should definitely **switch to 2**. You can learn about their differences [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html).

---

So you are probably talking about [Quick Controls 2 **Label**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html) and [Quick Control 2 **Text**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html).

Under **Inherits** you can always find from where that type inherits if it does. This helps to understand the flow of how these elements are all built. We can see that **`Text` inherits from an `Item`**, and **`Label` inherits from `Text`**:

> Label extends Text with styling and font inheritance. The default colors and font are style specific. Label can also have a visual background item.